# How to get Metadata of an object retrieved from amazon S3 in android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am retrieving an object from amazon s3.How to get metadata of retrieved object in android? From the metadata, i want to find out whether that object is image or Non-image (like pdf, csv, ...)

Thanks for any help.

I am using the following code for getting list of names under a folder.

```
            AmazonS3Client s3Client;
        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(
                Constants.ACCESS_KEY_ID, Constants.SECRET_KEY));

        ObjectListing objListOfPath = s3Client.listObjects(
                Constants.getPictureBucket(), path);
        List<S3ObjectSummary> keyListOfObjectSummaries = objListOfPath
                .getObjectSummaries();
        ObjectListing next = s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objListOfPath);
        keyListOfObjectSummaries.addAll(next.getObjectSummaries());
        System.out.println("keyListOfObjectSummaries size() "
                + keyListOfObjectSummaries.size());

        ArrayList<String> arrListImageName = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (keyListOfObjectSummaries.size() > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < keyListOfObjectSummaries.size(); i++) {
                String imagePath = keyListOfObjectSummaries.get(i).getKey();
                                    arrListImageName.add(strImageName);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arrListImageName.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Index " + i + " image Name "
                        + arrListImageName.get(i));
                String strReceiptImageName = arrListImageName.get(i);
                String strReceiptNameExtension = extractReceiptNameExtension(arrListImageName.get(i));


                S3Object objectReceiptFromAmazonS3 = s3Client.getObject(
                        Constants.PICTURE_BUCKET, keyListOfObjectSummaries
                                .get(i).getKey());
                InputStream inputStreamReceiptObject = objectReceiptFromAmazonS3
                        .getObjectContent();
```

SOLUTION:

```
System.out.println("CONTENT TYPE " +objectReceiptFromAmazonS3.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());
```

Thanks to Harshit and sanket !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has worked for me to download a file hosted in S3 from a simple servlet.

```
private static final int BYTES_DOWNLOAD = 1024;
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String key = request.getParameter("key");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String bucketname = (String) session.getAttribute("BUCKETNAME");
    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(Constants.credentials);
    Region usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
    s3.setRegion(usWest2);
    S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketname, key));        
    response.setContentType(object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+object.getKey());
    InputStream is = object.getObjectContent();int read=0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[BYTES_DOWNLOAD];
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream(); 
while((read = is.read(bytes))!= -1){
    os.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
os.flush();
os.close(); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this couple of lines :

```
ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata(); 
metaData.addUserMetadata("key", key of your file);
System.out.println("Content type is========"+metaData.getContentType());
```

this might be help you..

Comment: you want to download or upload.